# Not Drawing Lines in Between Comments

Tags: bug

I was just [having an extensive conversation with an OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613677/pygame-i-need-to-have-obstacles-repeat-randomly/36613850#36613850), and I noticed that in the comments section, there were some lines not being drawn in between separate comments, as shown. I don't know if this happens on other machines or not.[image]

Comment: Are you zoomed out?

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes, that's just a small screenshot. Does it not show it on your machine?

Comment: [No repro here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rfMXt.png)